# Adding an else if statement to pull up a page in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, expressionengine

We have a new website developed by a outside company that we are having issues with. I am trying to figure out the logic on a piece of code that would pull up a new page if some requirements are met.

First of all this is the site http://www.winstonind.com/service

For any servicer in the US it pulls up a Google map and the locations of our servicers for any other options in the drop-down it doesn't do anything. what I would like to know is how I would make is so if china is selected it would go to a page I created with the list of servicers from that region can you help me with this? I don't understand alot of Javascript yet and I cant tinker alot since the site is live.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $("#country").change(function(){
                    $(this).val()!='default'?$("#state").hide():$("#state").show();
                });
                var typeChoice;
                $("#step1next").click(function(){
                    typeChoice = $(".mt:checked").val();
                    $(".step.1").removeClass('selected');
                    $(".step.2").addClass('selected');
                    $(".step.1 .sContent").slideUp();
                    $(".step.2 .sContent").slideDown();
                });
                $("#step2next").click(function(){
                    if(typeChoice == 'type1')
                    {
                        $("#mapResult").html('<p style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:5px;">For all service requests that are in-warranty please contact Winston Industries directly.</p><p style="text-align:center;">Toll free: 1-800-234-5286<br/>International: +1-502-495-5400</p>');
                    }else{
                        $("#mapResult").html('');
                        var zip='';
                        $("#state").val()==$("#state").attr('default')?zip='':zip=$("#state").val();

                        //to make distance dynamic, replace 50 with a dynamic value
                        $.post('service/getMap/'+zip+'/50',function(data){
                            $("#mapResult").html(data);
                        });
                    }
                    $(".step.2").removeClass('selected');
                    $(".step.3").addClass('selected');
                    $(".step.2 .sContent").slideUp();
                    $(".step.3 .sContent").slideDown();
                });
                $(".sContent").hide();
                $(".selected .sContent").show();
            </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even bother to think they used jQuery for this how can you tell?

Comment: $ is typically used for jQuery. Other frameworks and code can define $ as well, but from methods used `addClass`, `removeClass` and others are specific to jQuery.

Comment: Thank you Justin 808 can you recommend a good book for a jQuery beginner?

Comment: if you know javascript in general, using the jQuery website - http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page - is the best way I would recommend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following before your closing  and modify the url to point to the correct directory and url.

```
if($('#country').val() == 'china'){
    window.location = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/chinaServicesPage';
}


if($('#country').val() == 'canada'){
    window.location = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/swedishServicesPage';
}

</script>
```

This is what your select box code looks like:

```
<select name="country" id="country">
                        <option value="default">United States</option>

                        <option value="canada">Canada</option>

                        <option value="china">Greater China</option>

                        <option value="asia_excluding_china">Asia (excluding Greater China)</option>

                        <option value="europe">Europe</option>

                        <option value="latin_america_and_the_caribbean">Latin America and the Caribbean</option>

                        <option value="middle_east">Middle East</option>

                        <option value="africa">Africa</option>

                        <option value="southernpacific">Southern Pacific</option>

                        <option value="united_states">United States</option>

                    </select>
```

You will notice that the "id" in the first line is called country. so we want to read the value that the user has placed in the select box of country which could be canada, china, USA, etc...

Comment: Where would type 3 come from? could you explain it to me I'm new to this.

Comment: I have modified the code to your actual Document elements... so it is checking if the value of the div named country is 'china' then it will go to a certain page.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is somewhat what you wanted:

```
if(thisThing){ 
   window.location = 'urlA';
}
else { 
   window.location = 'urlB';
}
```